# Matplotlib: how to have different label for marker and color

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame with (date, col1, col2, year, month) and I would like to plot (col1, col2) on scatter with different markers to each year and different color for each month. Below code plot the scatter plot with differnt markers for each year and different color for each month.

```
markers = plt.Line2D.markers.keys()[::-1]
for i, year in enumerate(np.unique(df_begin.year)):
    df_year = df_begin[df_begin['year'] == year]
    for j, month in enumerate(np.unique(df_year.month)):
        df_month = df_year[df_year['month'] == month]
        plt.scatter(df_month['col1'], df_month['col2'], marker=markers[i], color=palette[j], facecolor='none', s=20)

plt.show()
```

I want to create label on the chart for years ie. marker and color for month e.g. label would show x (marker) -> 2004 and red (color - Jan

Is there any way to achive this in matplotlib ?

Any help much apprecaited.